# What is the function of (app/build.gradle) FlutterVersionName?

Tags: android, flutter

I have updated flutter to 2.5 but the mentioned field of FlutterVersionName in app/build.gradle is still 1. Should that be updated to the current flutter version?

What is the function of that field?

[image]

Comment: That seems to be app version name. I am yet to confirm. will edit this when confirmed

Comment: @Tonui probably not, that one is inside yaml file.